# Replace woocommerce | (pipe) separator in product variation to , or another character?

Tags: plugins, e-commerce, localization

How to replace Woocommerce `|` (pipe) separator in product variation to `,` or another character?

I use Cyrillic keyboard layout and there is no pipe symbol. To enter that symbol I have to switch to English layout, enter `|` and switch back. I have hundreds of variations of products.

Comment: Solution for this problem is located in two files writepanels-product_data.php and in woocommerce-ajax.php just replace `|` in implode (' | ') explode (' | ') with `*`
Disadvantage of thisway is after update all your edits will be lost!
I will be very happy to see your advices!

Comment: Now i faced another problem! In front view variations is missed

Answer (score 1):

Type Alt + 124 for the vertical pipe symbol instead of changing language

Answer (score 0):

There is probably not a way to change that, but if you post this as an "issue" at Woo's github: https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues they might be able to add a filter to core that would let you change it.  Better still, if you can find a solution, they're even more likely to include the code.

I could see something like:

```
// Text based, separate by pipe
$seperator = apply_filters('woocommerce_variations_seperator', '|' );

$values = implode( ' '.$seperator.' ', array_map( 'woocommerce_clean', array_map( 'stripslashes', explode( $seperator, $attribute_values[ $i ] ) ) ) );
```

Which shouldn't break any backcompatibility, while still allowing you to use a different character there.  *Totally* untested.